# How can I pass parameters to a Services endpoint?

Tags: 7, services

I have installed Drupal 7 and enabled [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) in it. I have also created an endpoint `/api/v2/` and in resources, I have allowed nodes to be listed as JSON.

I have sent a `GET` request using browser or POSTMAN to `/api/v2/node` then I am getting following results.

```
 [
 {
 nid: "3143",
 vid: "3932",
 type: "event_calendar",
 language: "en",
 title: "EVENTS STILL APPEAR ON FRONT PAGE WHEN EVENT HAS ENDED - with or w     ithout an END DATE ",
 uid: "139",
 status: "1",
 created: "1560282811",
 changed: "1560282922",
 comment: "1",
 promote: "0",
 sticky: "0",
 tnid: "0",
 translate: "0",
 uuid: "",
 uri: "http://..../api/v2/node/3143"
 },
...
 ]`
```

If I send a request to `http://..../api/v2/node/[nid]` then I am getting an individual record of that node. 
Now I want to get post parameters to the endpoint. For example, I want to get all nodes with type = event_calendar.

I have tried posting parameters like `http://..../api/v2/node?type=event_calendar` but unfortunately, It is still showing list of all nodes. I have tried thing using POSTMAN and browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `http://domain/api/v2/node?parameters[type]=event_calendar`

any of the identifiers need to use inside parameters[]

Also, you can use [services views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) module to expose the data and create new identifiers like `type` on your own.